New-AzApiManagementSubscription in Powershell to create a Subscription in Azure APIM
I try to create a subscription in Azure APIM with:
New-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $Context  -Name "test-01"    -Scope "/products/test-ericf" -Verbose

but always receive error message:
New-AzApiManagementSubscription: 
Error Code: ValidationError
Error Message: One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Request Id: 7fc113c3-83af-4c6d-9e50-6825aefb3817
Error Details:
        [Code= ValidationError, Message= Invalid field 'ownerId' specified, Target= ownerId]

Any ideas?
I also tried with -debug, and got the error:
New-AzApiManagementSubscription: 
Error Code: ValidationError
Error Message: One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Request Id: c6a6e092-66ac-4886-9569-d9a6c8e7cb17
Error Details:
        [Code= ValidationError, Message= Invalid field 'ownerId' specified, Target= 


Any other command did you try?

Are you looking for only powershell approach?

Invalid owner id occurs when you want to associate a subscription to the specific user under APIM. To avoid this kind of issues, retrieve the assigned users from APIM in the below format first.
$Context = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "Jahnavi" -ServiceName "newapimjah"
Get-AzApiManagementUser -Context $Context


Take the respective userId from it and assign the subscription to the user as shown below.
New-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $Context -Scope "/products/sampleprod" -Name "newsubsc" -UserId 1


Alternatively, I have also tried with the default starter product without any user related information, and it worked as expected.
$Context = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "Jahnavi" -ServiceName "newapimjah"
New-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $Context -Scope "/products/starter" -Name "newsubsc"


Reference: MSDoc
